# Can We override **Add New Product** Page in custom_module on frontend area?

Tags: magento2, product, overrides, new-products

I want to make a custom page where **vendor** can add **New Product** with all text fields which Magento provide from the backend.

I want to override this same page on my custom module on the frontend side.

Is this possible?